# Eclipse Tomcat Failed to scan JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I replaced a `jar` in my `WebContent > Web-Inf > lib` and it looks like something went out of sync because I'm running into the `Failed to scan JAR` issue.

I tried the solutions offered around here:

1. Closing and reopening the project.
2. Restarting `Eclipse`.
3. Removing the `temp` directory in `tomcat` and recreating it.

But the problem persists. What am I missing?

Comment: I removed tomcat entirely from my Eclipse project, including the "Server Runtime Environment" and added it from scratch. Problem gone. (what a crappy situation to be in but at least I found a solution.)

Answer (score 0):

Check of these:

1)Does the jar has all the permissions.

2) Build path exactly refers to the path you specified

3)Instead of replace delete the previous jar and copy the new one and recreate the Build path and then scan it.

Comment: Yes, I did all these. No luck.